# GridView EditText and Update Text do not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0

and here is the HTML code:(GridView)

```
<asp:commandfield showeditbutton="true"
    edittext="abc"
    canceltext="Discard2"
    updatetext="Revise"
    headertext="Edit Controls"/>
```

No matter what I specify as `EditText` or `updatetext` they both always show as "Edit". `canceltext` shows correctly:

[image]

---

**Update:** My apologies for late update as I got this spaghetti huge code from someone who left:

I have no distant clue why he uses the following code in RowDataBound:

```
if (theServiceLineIsEditable)
{
   editLinkButton.Text = "Edit";                            
}
else
{
   editLinkButton.Text = "";
}
```

This clearly overrides the `EditText` and `updateText` behavior.

Can anyone think of any use of that code?

Comment: ================================
Update: My appologies for late update: As I got this spogeties huge code from someone who left:

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the person before you was trying to hide the Edit button on specific conditions when the better option would be to just set visibility to false. I have used this type of code before in a condition when a check has been posted so we do not want the user to be able to edit the check information anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for using above code in RowDataBound is that whenever you bind your GridView with DataSource `GridView1.DataBind();`, it always calls the RowDataBound event of GridView in which you can apply formatting and can customize your rows and cells of GridView and also its Text or Data.